# Deploying an EAR with EJBs and dependencies on JBoss

Tags: jboss, dependencies, ejb

I'm trying to deploy a maven generated ear in a fresh installed **Jboss EAP 6.1.** The ear deploys well on Glassfish 2.x. The ear structure is this:

```
    Ear_name-deploy-X.X.X.ear
    |- META-INF
    |  |- maven
    |  |  |
    |  |  \-Ear_name -> Ear_name-deploy -> pom.properties
    |  |                                -> pom.xml
    |  |- application.xml
    |  |- MANIFEST.MF
    |  \- sun-application.xml
    \- some jars (around 100)
```

Some of those jars are EJBs wich have dependencies on other jars in the same bundle and those dependencies are failing. I know I have to include a **jboss-deployment-structure.xml** file in META-INF folder. But I don't find how to define those dependencies without having to establish the jars as modules, what I don't want to do. Isn't there another way to stablish those dependencies? Thank you all for your time.